# How can I compress a markov transition probability matrix?

Tags: matrices, markov-chains

I'm performing a simple experiment. I have a markov transition matrix and I need to know how to compute a transition similarity matrix using spears algorithm. I'm following this paper(pages 8 and 9)

http://oro.open.ac.uk/2963/4/hong.pdf

I understand how to get the graph, the original probability matrix but I don't know how the original matrix gets converted to the transition similarity matrix.

Anyone can explain how to get similarity matrix from the original one??

Original matrix:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/06lf2.png

Comment: Why not actually look up the Spears algorithm? I easily found the original paper: http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0895479897316916 The  transformation to the transition similarity matrix in particular appears to be written out in detail in the paper you linked on page 66.

Comment: yes but for some reason I don't get how he gets the similarity matrix? Can you help me with one example?

Comment: What's the problem with following the recipe given on page 66? I haven't used this particular technique so I don't want to learn it just to help you with it, but that recipe seems detailed enough.